# How to call my own defined method from Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, remoting, error-log

I have created a public method In my Service to write an error log from my client machine as

```
 public partial class ATEServiceLog : ServiceBase
 {
    public ATEServiceLog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
            TcpChannel tcp = new TcpChannel(9090);
            ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(tcp, false);
            RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(typeof(AteBAC), "ATE", WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);  
    }
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
    }
    public void OnWriteErrorLog(string error)
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath+@"\ATELogCheck.txt", true))
        {
            file.WriteLine(error);
        }         
    }
}
```

I have created the last method to write logs. How can I call this method from my client machine. I tried something like

```
NetNamedPipeBinding binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding();
ATEService.ATEServiceLog myService = new ATEService.ATEServiceLog(binding,
                                 new EndpointAddress("tcp://localhost/ATEServiceLog"));
myService.OnWriteErrorLog("Error From My Client");
```

It is giving compile time error as `'ATEService.ATEServiceLog' does not contain a constructor that takes '2' arguments`. How can I call my method. How to implement the error logging in the server. My service will run on server and will have multiple clients. I have to write all the clients errors in server using windows service.

Comment: Why don't you fix the error you receive first? It says quite clearly what is wrong.

Comment: Why? Your class doesn't have a constructor with 2 arguments you are trying to use. It only has a constructor with no arugments. Either add a new constructor to your class or use the existing one in your client machine code. After you do that, you can really start wondering if your solution works or not.

Comment: The client side code is incorrect. Tell if you want it TCP or Pipes and I will show you a working example